# How to disable the "Safely Remove Hardware" icon from the System Tray

Tags: windows, system-tray

When plugging in a USB device the "Safely Remove Hardware" icon/option appears in the System Tray.  Is there any way to disable this so it doesn't show at all?

I cannot use an option like a program or anything that have to be installed and/or kept running.  The only option I really have is a registry or setting during Windows Deployment.

This is to be used on 2000+ cash registers so I couldn't care less if one cannot "safely" remove the USB device they happen to plug into the cash register.

Answer (score -1):

click the `arrow`->`Customize`

then you get **`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Notification Area Icons`**  window.

Here you can have 3 options for each icon. And select **`hide icon and notification`** option.

Comment: You are missing the point. I don't want it hidden, but completely disabled/removed. Also no clicking involved as it has to be done during Windows Deployment as previously described.